# Popover is not showing image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Onmouse hover ,popover is showing only title not the image

Code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


var img ='<img src="/assets/Excel_1.png">';

$("#blob").popover({ title: 'Format for Excel sheet', content: img , trigger:'hover' });

});
</script>
```

In Body:

```
 <i href="#" id="blob" class="icon-info-sign" rel="popover"  style="margin-top: 300px"> </i>
```

But not showing image.....

Thanks

Comment: What error you get on console..???

Comment: there's nothing here to do with ruby, rails or grails; this is jQuery code.

Comment: I mean browser console....

Comment: Where did you get this popover plugin from ? it does not seem to be from jquery UI.

Comment: I am using twitter bootstrap.....

Comment: href is not allowed on an <i> element. use data-href instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution of this simple problem...

```
$("#blob_1").popover({ title: 'Format for Excel sheet', content: img , trigger:'hover',html: true });
```

Just this change made the need possible

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: http://jsbin.com/iducul/1/edit

Html is:

```
<a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover">hover for popover</a>
```

jQuery is:

```
$(function (){ 
    var img = '<img src="https://si0.twimg.com/a/1339639284/images/three_circles/twitter-bird-white-on-blue.png" />';
    $("#example").popover({title: 'Twitter Bootstrap Popover', content:img});  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't closed the image tag. May be this is the problem:

```
var img ='<img src="/assets/Excel_1.png">';
```

It should be:

```
var img ='<img src="/assets/Excel_1.png"></img>';
```